# Reducing algorithm for SHA256 rainbow tables

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, sha256, reducing

I am doing a project on cracking sha256 using rainbow tables. I am trying to attack 8 digit alphanumeric sequences. I understand exactly how rainbow tables work and how the chains are supposed to be formed and stored. However, I do not understand how to get a reducing function to form the chains. I have googled and thought about it myself for hours, with no results. So, what is a good reducing function for the chains and how can it prove that it covers all 8 digit alphanumeric sequences.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about developing cryptanalysis techniques and doesn't include a programming question.

Comment: @Duncan One could argue that it is a question about a software algorithm, which is on-topic according to the help center. Stack Overflow is not only for programming questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 10^9 distinct sequences of 8 digits. There are 1073741824 possible values for the first 30 bits of a SHA256 hash value. So one reasonable approach would be to extract those 30 bits and use that number modulo 10^9 as your reduction function:

```
R(hash) = hash[0:30] % 10^9
```

It is unlikely that this actually covers all 8 digit sequences, but in practice it should definitely good enough due to assumed "randomness" properties of SHA256. There is a small bias towards numbers <= 2^30 - 10^9 though because of the modulus.